# How to plot 1/x in the range {x,0,5}?

Tags: plotting

How do you plot `1/x` in the range `{x,0,5}`? As at `x=0`, there occurs a singularity in the function. Is it possible to  plot this type of function near the `x=0` limit?

Comment: What do you mean by plotting it near the limit?? You can use Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 5}] or even with range {x,-1,1} and you'll get a plot that hides diverging parts. When you set `PlotRange` to `All` you'll get big values. I can't imagine what would you like to see on that graph as it's only a function getting bigger and bigger as `x` tends to zero.

Comment: Welcome! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Try `Plot[1/x, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you'll never be able to plot this function *entirely*, it is, after all, diverging to infinity. But maybe this will also be of help:

```
Table[
 Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 5.5}, {-i/10, i}}],
 {i, {10, 100, 1000}}]
```

> [image: plots]

Not really much to see, is there?

PS Please do excuse my working with non-standard options set for `Plot` at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot near the singularity by using

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 5}, Exclusions -> 0]
```